# error in mysql code written for ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

while running the below mysql query in ruby on rails

```
cnt=Domainurl.find_by_sql["SELECT MAX(`count`) FROM domainurls WHERE `domaindetail_id` = ?", @domain.id]
puts cnt.count
```

I am getting below error:

```
"error is: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"
```

Can anybody tell where exactly am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You either need to wrap the argument in parenthesis or add a space.

```
cnt=Domainurl.find_by_sql(["SELECT MAX(`count`) FROM domainurls WHERE `domaindetail_id` = ?", @domain.id])
```

or

```
cnt=Domainurl.find_by_sql ["SELECT MAX(`count`) FROM domainurls WHERE `domaindetail_id` = ?", @domain.id]
```